# Downloaded Node Module has unrecognized function

Tags: node.js, npm, cucumber-jvm

I recently did an npm install of the following module -
https://github.com/gkushang/cucumber-html-reporter

I edited the index.js according to the **Usage** but when I do a -
"node index.js", node complains that **reporter.generate** is not a recognized function.

Could someone take a look and help me debug this? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- fork this repo to your own github account.
- Fix the bug.
- PR to the original repo.
- ask this guy commit a new version for this package on npmjs.com.

Comment: I don't have the skills to do that. I was hoping someone could take a look at it for me. Many people have used this module, so I think the issue is on my side. I have tried contacting this person, but he does not respond.